Calculating kernel density home ranges of animals in QGIS
I am trying to calculate the kernel density home ranges of some animal occurrences in QGIS. I found the following website with a model:
https://plugins.qgis.org/models/19/
How do I import it and run it in QGIS?

In the Processing Toolbox click the cogs then choose "Open Existing Model...", then hit the run button.
Or in the Processing Toolbox click the cogs then choose "Add Model to Toolbox...", then find the model in the Models tree in the Toolbox and double-click it to open its dialog.
